Can't fix WordPress Docker container volume mount file permissions
No matter what I do, I can't fix the file permissions of the volume mount of the official WordPress Docker image.
The mounted volume files cannot be deleted or modified, they are owned by a user with a random id, like 525287.

Here's my docker-compose.yml.
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:9.0.0
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wp
            MYSQL_USER: admin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
    wordpress:
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        build:
            context: .
        volumes:
            - ./data/wp:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wp
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: admin
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: admin
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        image: phpmyadmin:5.2.1
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root


Here's my Dockerfile.
FROM wordpress:6.6.0-php8.3-apache

RUN usermod --uid 1000 www-data && \
    groupmod --gid 1000 www-data && \
    chown -R www-data /var/www/html && \
    echo 'This is not working'


For some reason, the RUN commands are never actually run.
I'm using Fedora Linux.

I have tried adding user: 1000:1000, it only breaks the WordPress image (creates a bunch of permission denied messages)
